# Processing an Object During Fetch Returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fetching an API of dogs, it returns an object. 
I want to make changes in the object before I convert 
it to an array and setState() it. 
Problem is it returns 'undefined'.
I assume the function is ok because it does work if I run in outside the fetch, or maybe I'm missing something here?

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
      (res => res.json())
      .then(res => res.message)
      .then(res => this.processReq(res)) // <--- undefined
      .then(res => Object.entries(res))
      .then(res => this.setState({ allBreeds: res }));
  }

  processReq = breed =>
    Object.keys(breed).forEach(key => {
      if (key === "australian") {
        breed["shepherd"] = [key];
        delete breed[key];
      } else if (key === "germanshepherd") {
        breed["shepherd"].push("german");
        delete breed[key];
      }
    });
```

Is there a way to manipulate the object during the fetch?
Or maybe it would be easier to setState() it as an array and then process it?

Comment: why are you using so many then?

Comment: What would be a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Actually `forEach` function doesn't return anything so that's why it's giving `undefined`, you should change it to:

```
processReq = breed => {
    Object.keys(breed).forEach(key => {
      if (key === "australian") {
        breed["shepherd"] = [key];
        delete breed[key];
      } else if (key === "germanshepherd") {
        breed["shepherd"].push("german");
        delete breed[key];
      }
    });
    return breed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `processReq` function doesn't have a return statement, so it just returns `undefined`. Just put a `return breed;` on the end of it and you'll be fine.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project!

Comment: That's incorrect, it's an implicitly returning arrow function, it's just that `forEach` return value is `undefined`.

Comment: Afraid not - the callback in .then() invokes the processReq function and returns the result, which is undefined.

Comment: Arrow functions don't implicitly return if they're in curly braces

Comment: Hmmm, you're right! Could have sworn they were there a moment ago! Will correct my answer.